# Change route after status 200

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios

Im trying to change my route to /despesas after i get the login status to work(status:200).

```
async EnvioLogin() {
  const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  });
  localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);

  const status = JSON.parse(response.data.response.status);
  if (status == "200") {
    this.$router.push("/despesas");
  } else {
    showError(true), setTimeout(showError(false), 3000);
  }
},
```

When i login and inspect in my browser this message appears:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"
```

Comment: Looks like you have one too many `response`'s in `response.data.response.status`.

Comment: should it be just response.status  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `response.data.response.status` is undefined.

Place a `console.log(response)` above the line where you call it and check for the right structure.

Most probably will be `response.status`

Comment: i did JSON.parse(response.status)(worked) with a console.log(response). A new error appears is:                               Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/despesas".

Comment: That's probably because you are making that request from /despesas route

Comment: Try const path = `/despesas`
if (this.$route.path !== path) this.$router.push(path)

Comment: Note that the route tip is a bit of a workaround. You should probably fix your routes or the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `response.status` or simply you can do check...

```js
if (response.ok) {
  /* do something */
} else {
  /* do something */
}
```

*response.ok* is similar to what you have in `statusText: ok`:

```json
{data: {...}, status: 200, statusText: "ok", .... }
```